# Using a JavaScript function to add data to a string that comes from the HTML document, and preserving that data after that function is called again

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote an object called TypeWriter2 and then I want to add it a function called type2().

I then call the TypeWriter2 object using a function called init2(), which queries some data from the html document and passes it to the TypeWriter2 object.

The data that init2() is querying from the html document is:

1. txtElement2 = a div element, that the type2() function will use to display some data.
2. words2 = the words that are to be displayed in txtElement2, which is "Hello, there...  Yoo"
3. wait2 = an int that will be passed to setTimeout() later on.

The type2() function is meant is meant of add "iiiiii" to "txt2" (an empty string at the beginning), whenever "txt2" ends with 3 consecutive dots.

The problem being that after "iiiiii" is added to "txt2" and "setTimeout(() => this.type2(), this.wait2);" is called again, "iiiiii"  is being deleted from "txt2".

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init2);

const TypeWriter2 = function (txtElement2, words2, wait2 = 3000) {
    this.txtElement2 = txtElement2;
    this.words2 = words2;
    this.wait2 = parseInt(wait2, 10);
    this.txt2 = '';
    this.type2();
}

TypeWriter2.prototype.type2 = function () {
    this.txt2 = this.words2.substring(0, this.txt2.length + 1)

    if (this.txt2.substr(this.txt2.length - 3) === "...") {
        this.txt2 = this.txt2 + "iiiii"
        this.txtElement2.innerHTML = `<span class="intro-text">${this.txt2}</span>`;

    } else {
        this.txtElement2.innerHTML = `<span class="intro-text">${this.txt2}</span>`;
   }

    setTimeout(() => this.type2(), this.wait2);

}


function init2() {

    const txtElement2 = document.querySelector('.intro-text');
    const words2 = txtElement2.getAttribute('hello-txt');
    const wait2 = txtElement2.getAttribute("data2-wait");

    new TypeWriter2(txtElement2, words2, wait2);

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you try `this.txtElement2.innerHTML += '<span...`? This will append to the existing innerHTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to reproduce the bug as described using the posted code, but in all likelihood you can resolve the problem by changing your `else` statement to an `else if` such that the type2 method stops being called as soon as all of the text in the "hello-txt" attribute has been added to `txtElement2.innerHTML`

Attempted repro case: https://jsbin.com/wovatit/1/edit?html,js,output

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init2);

const TypeWriter2 = function (txtElement2, words2, wait2 = 3000) {
    this.txtElement2 = txtElement2;
    this.words2 = words2;
    this.wait2 = parseInt(wait2, 10);
    this.txt2 = '';
    this.type2();
}

TypeWriter2.prototype.type2 = function () {
  console.log('called');
    this.txt2 = this.words2.substring(0, this.txt2.length + 1)

    if (this.txt2.substr(this.txt2.length - 3) === "...") {
        this.txt2 = this.txt2 + "iiiii"
        this.txtElement2.innerHTML = `<span class="intro-text">${this.txt2}</span>`;
        console.log("finished")
    } else if(this.txt2.length <= this.words2.length){
        this.txtElement2.innerHTML = `<span class="intro-text">${this.txt2}</span>`;
        setTimeout(() => this.type2(), this.wait2);
    } else{
      console.log("finsished")
    }


}


function init2() {
    const txtElement2 = document.querySelector('.intro-text');
    const words2 = txtElement2.getAttribute('hello-txt');
    const wait2 = txtElement2.getAttribute("data2-wait");
    new TypeWriter2(txtElement2, words2, wait2);

}
```